# Why was J# not supported in VS 2008, is the language dead?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, j#

Has MS given up on J# ?  We integrate with software currently through a J# assembly.  Does anyone know if it will be/is supported in 2010?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a link that answers your question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualjsharpgeneral/thread/3fbac9ac-c43a-4c7f-9fee-1bc1de2c6fc5

It was discontinued after VS2005.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/default.aspx <-- It has been retired.

Answer (score 1):

I think the existence of J# was really to promote the CLR.  Now that we have projects like Iron/NameHere/ I suspect the point was received by the community.  Last big update from the J# team was years ago and it exists now as a demonstration of what the CLR is capable of.