# imports java.util.zip in a vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, dll, import

I need to import java.util.zip for my project to zip and unzip chosen files/folders in vb.net. But when i say imports java.util.zip, i get the error "Namespace cannot be found". I went in the add reference and checked in both .net and COM components bout found nothing for java.
What dll would i need to make this work?

thanks

Comment: You tagged this "java" and are trying to import a Java class, but you aren't using Java. I'm very confused as to what you are trying to do...

Comment: I'm sure there are .NET ways to zip and unzip folders. Use those instead of trying to call java from VB

Comment: @jean-bernard - Im sure there are, but thats not what this question is about. If you plan to give general answers, please do not answer this question.

Comment: What version of .NET and Visual Studio are you using?  J# was retired with Visual Studio 2008 (i.e. 2008 did _not_ support J# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654959/why-was-j-not-supported-in-vs-2008-is-the-language-dead), so I don't think you'll be able to use a Java library past Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: @bdukes. Thank you for your help. is there any replacement for the java library in VS2008? I'm using VS2008.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a direct analogue, I'd look into libraries point to below (or open another question on here to get suggestions of the best/easiest way to implement zipping)

Comment: Google for SharpZipLib which can be used in C#/VB.Net.

Answer (score 3):

If you need zip/unzip using a pure managed code library, you should to take a look at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)

Answer (score 1):

You might be talking about some ancient J# library, in which case you'll have to reference vjslib.dll

Don't do that though.

Use a sane,small Zip library, such as [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)